# How to turn fields in a text file into terms in kibana

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a text file, formmated like JSON:

```
"changedFieldsList": [
{
  "fieldId": "ORDER_ID",
  "fieldType": "NUMBER",
  "fieldValue": "55841",
  "fieldChanged": "Y"
},
{
  "fieldId": "ORDER_DATE",
  "fieldType": "DATE",
  "fieldValue": "2017-11-13",
  "fieldChanged": "Y"
}...
]
```

Currently, kibana (after receiving the file like so: folders -> filebeat -> logstash -> elasticsearch -> kibana) takes the entire text file as one, and I cant aggregate the file by its fields, like sort by fieldID or by value.

How can I make logstash/kibana to process the data so that the keys in the JSON file are terms kibana can sort by?

How can I make the elastic stack deal with the JSON format (and again - this is not a .json file, its a text file) better?

I tried to use JSON filters in logstash, but couldn't make it, so far.

P.S:

There is another thing I'm trying to do: when I discover the data in kibana, kibana shows the file path under "source". Can I get out a portion of the path and save it as a searchable term?

for example:

/path/to/the/folder/FOLDERNAME/subdir/file

I want to save FOLDERNAME as a variable I can aggregate the data by.
Can anyone help?

Yishai

Comment: You need to make sure the fields are mapped as "keyword". You can't aggregate on "text" fields. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/keyword.html

Comment: @Miek:
Thanks for the answer. I mapped the field as keywords, and now when I use Discover the data shows like I want to:  "fieldType": "VARCHAR2" (for example) , but I still can't aggregate by the terms ("fieldType" in the example above. I want to show all the different values of fieldType).